# how can i import data from sql to c#

Tags: c#, sql

Hi guys i am working on a project. My project save the course name, its credit and my grades on c# to sql. This is ok.I handle it that but.I cant take datas to the compute the my average grades. I want to take my grades data in string array.could you help me please

Comment: Please add more information, like what kind of sql, what is your actual goal and what have you accomplished until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string connStr = "Enter your conneciton string here";
            string SQL = "Enter your SQL here";

            //uncomment lines below
            //SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, connStr);
            //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //adapter.Fill(dt);

            //simulated table
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "John", 22, "NY" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Mary", 27, "Boston" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Paul", 18, "Chicago" });


            int count = 0;
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Row {0} : {1}", (count++).ToString(), string.Join(",", row.ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: thank you for your help. I didnt mean that .i think i cant complain my issue clearly.